# How to get Lucene explanation for a SolrDocument with Solrj?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I'm searching an Solr index with SolrJ and trying to get the Lucene explanation for logging it for further use.

The code goes like this:

```
    SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("solr_url");
    SolrQuery solrquery = new SolrQuery();
    solrquery.set("fl", "score, id"); // id is a String field
    solrquery.set("rows", "1000");
    solrquery.set("debugQuery", "on");
    solrquery.setQuery("query words here");

    try {
        QueryResponse response = server.query(solrquery);
        SolrDocumentList docs = response.getResults();
        Iterator<SolrDocument> dociterator = docs.iterator();

        while (dociterator.hasNext())
        {
            SolrDocument doc = dociterator.next();
            String id = (String) doc.getFirstValue(idfield);
            Float relevance = (Float) doc.getFirstValue("score");
            String explanation = ???;
        }
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I figured that response.getEplainMap() would contain a map with the value like response.getEplainMap().get(id) , but it seems that the explainmap contains only the key null with the value of the last found document.

Any ideas how to get the correct explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case there was a bug in the Solr index itself. Code below works now.

```
Map<String, String> explainmap = response.getExplainMap();
String explanation = explainmap.get(id);
```

When creating an index and having problems like above make sure that the id field determined in schema.xml (e.g. `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`) contains correct data. In my case the id field I used in the code was not the same as Solr thought it was and it contained no data, thus the explainmap had only one field with a key null.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried debugging a query from the admin console? This shows you the full output.

`QueryResponse` has a couple of methods `getDebugMap()` and `getExplainMap()` that might prove useful. I haven't tested it in code but on the admin console when I debug a query I get the following;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="q">stuff</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="explainOther"/>
      <str name="wt">standard</str>
      <str name="hl.fl"/>
      <str name="fq"/>
      <str name="version">2.2</str>
      <str name="qt">standard</str>
      <str name="debugQuery">on</str>
      <str name="fl">*,score</str>
      <str name="rows">1</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="79" start="0" maxScore="4.050907">
    <doc>
      <float name="score">4.050907</float>
      ..other bits of data
     </doc>
  </result>
  <lst name="debug">
    <str name="rawquerystring">stuff</str>
    <str name="querystring">stuff</str>
    <str name="parsedquery">MYSEARCHFIELD:stuff</str>
    <str name="parsedquery_toString">MYSEARCHFIELD:stuff</str>
    <lst name="explain">
      <str name="6095">     <--- 6095 is the ID of the document
        4.050907 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(MYSEARCHFIELD:stuff in 1292), product of:
        1.4142135 = tf(termFreq(MYSEARCHFIELD:stuff )=2)
        9.166156 = idf(docFreq=79, maxDocs=281583)
        0.3125 = fieldNorm(field=MYSEARCHFIELD, doc=1292)
      </str>
    </lst>

    ..timing stuff here

  </lst>
</response>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my own answer the ids were wrong (read: non-existent). However, if I had read your answer before I figured out the problem by myself I would've seen my it from the debug query console since I believe the explain output didn't have the name/id -attribute at all like in your post. So in a way by posting that you solved my problem too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the explain information as a field in the document by passing in the special [explain] field (with square brackets) in the field list.